# What results exist for functions with regionally fluctuant fractal dimension?

Tags: reference-request, fractals

I'm interested in functions that have a varying fractal dimension at different scales and/or regions. Has this been investigated in detail? I'd be interested in results and references in this area of research.

Comment: I hear that this is something that can appear in "diffusion limited aggregation", if I am not mistaken, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation

Comment: try looking up multifractal analysis.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Do you have any references?

Comment: @ZacharyW.Robertson: Not really, but I get lots of hits on google; e.g. http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.85.021407

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I thought multifractal analysis was more about probability measures being fractal? Do you have a reference to what your talking about?

Comment: Possibly relevant to what you're looking for: [How can dimension depend on the point?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201321/how-can-dimension-depend-on-the-point)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Looks pretty good, thanks.

Comment: Something else possibly relveant: [**Fractured Fractals and Broken Dreams: Self-Similar Geometry through Metric and Measure**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0198501668) by Guy David and Stephen Semmes (1997). See the [review](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500020174) by Kenneth John Falconer and the [Zbl 887.54001 review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0887.54001).