# A set whose Hausdorff dimension gradually changes?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, fractals, dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Can there be a set whose Hausdorff dimension gradually changes?

For instance, a set of real numbers contained in an interval, whose Hausdorff dimension is 0 at the beginning and 1 closer to the end, and changes without jumps?

Comment: Take a sequence of [Cesaro fractals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CesaroFractal.html)

Comment: Related questions: [How can dimension depend on the point?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/201321/15780) *AND* [What results exist for functions with regionally fluctuant fractal dimension?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/214806/15780)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume you want a set $A\subseteq [0,1]$ such that $\dim (A\cap [0,x])=x$ for all $x$. We can define $A_1$ by taking the union of a (Borel) subset of dimension $0$ of $[0,1/2]$ with a subset of dimension $1/2$ of $[1/2,1]$.To obtain $A_2$, we then make our sets larger on $[1/4,1/2]$, $[3/4,1]$ and again, we make the dimension on each current interval equal to its left endpoint. Then $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq \ldots$, and $A=\bigcup A_n$ works: by monotone convergence, $h^d(I\cap A)=\lim h^d(I\cap A_n)$, so $A\cap [0,x]$ has the right dimension at each $x=k2^{-n}$ and thus everywhere.

Comment: Can we Lebesgue-integrate over such set?

Comment: @Anixx Each $A_n$ has Hausdorff dimension below $1$, so their (1-dimensional) Lebesgue measure is zero. So $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero. You can certainly integrate functions over null sets, but the results are not too interesting...

Comment: In fact for all $0<x\le1$  $A\cap[0,x]$  is an $x$-dimensional set of $x$-dimensional null measure, for the same reason.

Comment: Cool. I think a similar idea (reversing subintervals of $[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]$ as needed, for $n\rightarrow \infty, 0\le k<n$) can also be used to produce a set $A$ with *density* $x$ at $x$, i.e. $\mu(A\cap[0,x])=x^2/2$.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Are you sure? Doesn't that contradict Lebesgue Density Theorem?

Comment: @Wojowu you are right. So it must be that the procedure I had in mind doesn't converge (a.e. pointwise) to a well defined set.

Answer (score 5):

For an example of a different sort, you can consider the record set $R$ of a fractional Brownian motion with varying Hurst parameter $H(t)$. In [this short paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09726) it is shown that when $H(t)$ is constant, it equals the Hausdorff dimension of $R$. The properties of the fBM with varying Hurst parameter $H(t)$ are given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2870) for measurable functions $H(t)$ taking values in $(\tfrac12,1)$. One expects that the Hausdorff dimension of $R\cap (t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$ converges to $H(t)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.