# A generalized Hausdorff dimension in form of a Lower semi continuous function

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Let $(X,d)$ be  a  compact metric space. Assume  that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is  a positive continuous  function. We say that the $f$-dimension of $(X,d)$ is equal to $0$ if for  every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite open cover  $D_i,\;i=1,2,\ldots n $ consists of  open discs $D_i$  such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (diam D_i)^{f(t_i)} \leq \epsilon,\; \forall t_i\in D_i
$$

This  situation is  denoted  by $\mathcal{H}^f(X)=0$

We  define the  generalized Hausdorff  dimension of $X$ with
$$
dim(X)=\inf \{f\mid \mathcal{H}^f(X)=0\}
$$

So the dimension is no longer a number but a  lower semi-continuous function $f$.

> For  what kind of metric space is this dimension $f$ a continuous function? For  what kind of  metric spaces is this  dimension a constant function (equal to its Hausdorff dimension)?

Comment: No time now to think much about your question, and in any event it's likely that I don't know enough about possible metric space pathologies relevant in this context to say anything nontrivial, but possibly useful might be the references in my answers to [How can dimension depend on the point?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214470/15780) *AND* [Metric dimensions properties not in $\mathbb{R}^d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4169101/13130) *AND* [Existence of dimension function (i.e., exact gauge function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2915233/13130).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro  Thank you very much for the linked you share me.